Hello ,autocomplete does not mandatory parameters
I have a problem in Android Studio when working with Jetpack Compose. When I type Text or other Compose components, the autocomplete does not substitute mandatory parameters (e.g. text = “” for Text). Instead, just Text() is created. All autocomplete settings are enabled, but the problem doesn't go away. Maybe someone has encountered something similar or knows how to solve this problem?
Or are they not supposed to autocomplete? I've just seen in video tutorials that mandatory parameters are autocomplete.
I realize it's not really important, but it looks convenient.


did you found a solution? I have the same problem

Ensure Autocomplete is Enabled: Go to Preferences (or Settings on macOS) > Editor > General > Code Completion. Make sure Autopopup code completion is checked.
